# Make categories of RadPropertyGrid to invariant culture (English)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, telerik

Working with *Telerik UI for WinForms*, I have some `PropertyStoreItem` objects where I've assigned their categories as "**Data**" and "**Design**", however, the names of these categories are displayed in the current culture of the user (Spanish):

[image]

```
New PropertyStoreItem(propertyType:=GetType(Integer),
                      propertyName:="Refresh Interval",
                      value:=600,
                      description:="The interval, in seconds, to refresh the list contents.",
                      category:="Data",
                      [readOnly]:=False)
```

I know that modifying the current culture of the app does the trick, but how I can stop that behavior regardless of the culture of my application? I just want to change the culture behavior of the categories displayed by the control, not the culture of the entire app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the **ItemFormatting** event and hardcode these strings:

```
void radPropertyGrid1_ItemFormatting(object sender, PropertyGridItemFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item is PropertyGridGroupItem)
    {
        if (e.Item.Label == "Datos")
        {
            e.Item.Label = "Date";
        }
    }
}
```